# Physical source of photon frequency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, atomic-physics, frequency

In QM it's taught that the frequency of a photon emitted when an electron drops from a higher-energy state to a lower-energy state is $\Delta E/h$. In E&M, it's taught that the source of an electromagnetic wave is the acceleration of charge -- and that the frequency of the wave is the same as the frequency of oscillation in the acceleration of charge.    Is there a clear explanation of how *the electron's motion generates the frequency* when an electron drops from one energy state to a lower energy state in an atom?  Of course, I realize that the electron is really a wavefunction, not a particle, but still, *some* component of the electron (or electron wavefunction) must oscillate at the frequency $E/h$ during the transition from the high state to the low state.  What is that component?

Comment: Yes, Emilio posted an absolutely brilliant answer on exactly this point. Let me have a search for it ...

Comment: Aha, found it. I strongly recommend you read Emilio's answer to the question I've linked as it is the best explanation of hat is going on that I've ever seen.

Comment: @John Rennie Thank you for that link!  Actually, it looks more than a debate than a clear answer.  I wonder if the final answer might lie in observing that the frequency of the emitted photon is equal to the  difference (beat) frequency between zitterbewegung frequencies of the two states .

Comment: That said, Emilio's answer was indeed brilliant.